# How to call custom controller from index controller in Zend Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am newbie in Zend framework.And i have made sample project in netbeans.And it is working properly displaying index.phtml .But , I need to call my controller.What I have tried is below.

```
IndexController.php


<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        firstExample::indexAction();
    }    

}
```

And I have deleted all the content of index.phtml(just a blank file) , coz i don't want to render this view.
My custom controller is:

```
firstExampleController.php

<?php
class firstExample extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        self::sum();
    }

    public function sum(){
        $this->view->x=2;
        $this->view->y=4;
        $this->view->sum=x + y;
    }
}
?>

firstExample.phtml

<?php
echo 'hi';
echo $this->view->sum();
?>
```

How to display sum method in firstExample.php.

It just shows blank page after hitting below URL.

```
http://localhost/zendWithNetbeans/public/
```

I think after hitting on above URL , execution first goes to index.php in public folder.And I didn't change the content of index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using controller (MVC) incorrectly, Controller should not do any business logic, in your case sum method. Controller only responsible controlling request and glueing model and view together. That's why you have problems now calling it.

Create Model add method sum, and use in any controller you want. From controller you may pass model to view.

Here is example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html it uses database, but it's not necessary to use with database.

Basically your sum example could look like:

```
class Application_Sum_Model {

 public function sum($x, $y) {
   return ($x + $y);
 }
}

class IndexContoler extends Zend_Controller_Action {

   public function someAction() {

    $model = new Application_Sum_Model(); 

    //passing data to view that's okay
    $this->view->y   = $y;
    $this->view->x   = $x;
    $this->view->sum = $model->sum($x, $y); //business logic on mode

   }
}
```

Please read how controller is working, http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html

Comment: Do I need to change my default Bootstrap.php file?

Comment: no you don't, just add class to models directory and it will autoload. And then just create new object on required controller action.

Comment: Same problem I am facing after creating model.

firstExampleModel.php
<?php
class firstExampleModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
    public function sum(){
        $this->view->x=2;
        $this->view->y=4;
        $this->view->sum=x + y;
    }
}
?>

And in controller , I did create object of above class and than call sum method.

Comment: I don't know , how to indexController class will resolve that which controller has to call.Is my changes in above IndexController class is correct?

Comment: You can use any controller you want, i gave you only example. So you have basic idea.

Comment: can anyone please help in calling custom controller from starting?
I am suffering this problem.Please help me in this matter

Comment: there's a bug in your code. you got `init()` method, which is empty (so it is pointless to have it here) as you either shall remove it or call `parent::init();` there.

Comment: Thank you  Aurimas Lickus.I got u'r solution.But what I wanted to do that was something different.I didn't want to change my index controller and i wanted to made new controller that would revoke from index controller.
And one more thing i wanted to know that in "public" folder , there is index.php file.When I type above mentioned URL , than index.php is call , and my question is how this file get to know that indexcontroller class should be called.Is there any entry of that.Am i change to my custom controller?

Comment: I got my answer .I think it is not possible to call one controller from other.Because controller is invoked by server when a particular request come to server....But , i have learnt some MVC in spring.And i mapped request to controller in web.xml file.In Zend , where this kind of mapping can be done?

Comment: It's called, routing http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html